# Restrict access to certain websites based on user in windows or chrome browser

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, blocking, restrictions

I am trying to restrict access to websites for multiple schools at different locations. We are currently using windows 7 on most of our systems. And all our kids and staff have google apps for education login. Is there a way I can block certain sites from access?

Our current solution was to remove all the browsers and install only chrome. And block permission to install new software. Then we mandate login in chorme for them to use chrome browser. And we can block users access from google apps for educations admin panel based on individual user. But it failed because we were unable to mandate login by user in chrome. Can some one suggest a solution that does not cost much and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 (MITM)

Simple.

Deploy a few pfSense boxes at each school, make a Certificate Authority, deploy it to all PCs as trusted, give pfSense a signed cert (by your CA), and set up MITMing.

Once done, tell pfSense what it's to block.

Done.

### Option 2 (Portals and MITM)

Once again, using pfSense, deploy boxes, but set up captive portals (which can be setup to use AD DS (LDAP) authentication (with the added benefit of requiring students and staff to log in to the portal, before passing traffic on)) and have the captive portal pass traffic through:

- One pfSense external MITM router for staff
- One pfSense external MITM router for students

Done.

Comment: Access to sites vary from staff to staff. Also deploying equipment might be expensive since we are non profit and our fee is about $400 per year. Also few campuses have upto 4000 students. So is it possible to reduce the equipment?

Comment: @user899893 you could have one captive portal on each campus and thread everything through a centralized VM server running multiple pfSense instances